# Revoke SETSESSIONUSER Privilege

Tags: security, db2

I have a security compliance to meet where i want to revoke SETSESSIONUSER Privilege. I am getting error while revoking the privilege even tough i am using admin user

I can see the record inside syscat.surrogateauthids

```
db2 => SELECT GRANTOR , TRUSTEDID , TRUSTEDIDTYPE , SURROGATEAUTHID , SURROGATEAUTHIDTYPE FROM syscat.surrogateauthids

GRANTOR                                                                                                                          TRUSTEDID                                                                                                                        TRUSTEDIDTYPE SURROGATEAUTHID                                                                                                                  SURROGATEAUTHIDTYPE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------
DB2INST1                                                                                                                         SYSATSCONTEXT                                                                                                                    C             PUBLIC                                                                                                                           G                  

  1 record(s) selected.
```

But when i want to revoke the privileges getting error

```
REVOKE SETSESSIONUSER ON SYSATSCONTEXT FROM GROUP PUBLIC

SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "SYSATSCONTEXT" was found following "KE SETSESSIONUSER ON".  Expected tokens may include:  "USER".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.33.31
```

Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: Did you check the syntax in the docs?  See  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-revoke-setsessionuser-privilege  . You need to specify the ` ... ON USER ` and the next token has to be an authorization-name  (not a trusted-context as shown in your question).